# Authentication via CORS does not set HttpContext.User

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, fetch, asp.net-core-2.2

currently I am facing the following issue:
I am using CORS to authenticate via JavaScript Fetch API to my ASP.NET-CORE 2.2 WebAPI.
To do that, I am using the following code:

```
const resp = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    credentials: 'include',
    mode: 'cors'
});
```

where the `url` contains the link to my login API call.

The login call looks like the following:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Login/{username}/{password}")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string username, string password)
{
    var theUser = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(username);
    if (theUser == null)
    {
        return BadRequest(userNotExistingMessage);
    }
    var result = await signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(theUser, password, false, false);
    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
       return Ok(loginMessage);
    } else
    {
       return BadRequest(wrongPasswordMessage);
    }
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("AllowAll", builder =>
        {
            builder
            .AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowCredentials();
        });
    });

    // Authentication
    services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
    {
       sharedOptions.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        sharedOptions.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddCookie(
    CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
    options =>
    {
        options.LoginPath = "/api/account/Login";
        options.Cookie.Name = "AUTHCOOKIE";
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(365, 0, 0, 0);
        options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest;
        options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
    });

    services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;
        options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
    });

    // DB
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

    // Sessions
    services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
    services.AddSession(options =>
    {
        options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
        options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
        options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest;
        options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
    });

    services.AddMvc()
        .AddJsonOptions(options =>
        {
            options.SerializerSettings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
        }
    );
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseCors("AllowAll");

    // Authorization
    var cookiePolicyOptions = new CookiePolicyOptions
    {
        Secure = CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest,
        MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None
    };
    app.UseCookiePolicy(cookiePolicyOptions);

    // Session
    app.UseSession();
    app.Use((httpContext, nextMiddleware) =>
    {
        httpContext.Session.SetString(SessionVariables.CID, httpContext.Session.Id);
        return nextMiddleware();
    });

    app.UseMvc();
}
```

When I am adding Swagger and access Login everything works fine:
After signing in a user with `PasswordSignInAsync()`, the HttpContext.User is  set and can be accessed during the further work with the API.
But when I try to access my API from javascript with the previously shown fetch it appears that the HttpContext.User is not getting set. That is why I can't access any of it's properties that I have to.

I tried severel things to get this work but nothing worked. That is driving me crazy. Is somebody out there who can help me to solve that issue?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the security settings are not allowing JavaScript to access cookies.

You can try and see if the following (HttpOnly to None) works:

```
var cookiePolicyOptions = new CookiePolicyOptions
{
 Secure = CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest,
 MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None,
 //Try setting this
 HttpOnly = Microsoft.AspNetCore.CookiePolicy.HttpOnlyPolicy.None
};
```

And / Or (`options.Cookie.HttpOnly = false`):

```
 services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
            {
                sharedOptions.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                sharedOptions.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
    .AddCookie(
    CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
    options =>
    {
        options.LoginPath = "/api/account/Login";
        options.Cookie.Name = "AUTHCOOKIE";
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(365, 0, 0, 0);
        options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest;
        options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = false; // Try this
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've tried the solution but sadly it doesn't work for me.
Anyways I found a workaround (that I am not really happy with but it works for now): I am able to store the unique identifier of the user inside his session cookie after he logged on and use this to access his data.